# "Rails way" to execute a seml-complex query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-activerecord

I have a semi-complex query in a Rails 4 project that's using postgres.  I'd like to see if it's possible to translate the query to ActiveRecord / Arel and if the Rails convention is to use `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)` if it's necessary to execute raw SQL.

Here's a query I want to execute:

```
select
  sum(case when is_graded = true then 1 else 0 end) graded,
  sum(case when is_canceled = true then 1 else 0 end) canceled,
  sum(case when is_graded IS NULL and is_canceled IS NULL then 1 else 0 end) in_progress
from exams
where user_id = 1 and quiz_id = 114;
```

I want the result in the format:

```
{"graded"=>"2", "canceled"=>"2", "in_progress"=>"1"}
```

This gets me the answer I'm looking for, but it seems ugly and I want to see if there's a better way:

```
sql="select
  sum(case when is_graded = true then 1 else 0 end) graded,
  sum(case when is_canceled = true then 1 else 0 end) canceled,
  sum(case when is_graded IS NULL and is_canceled IS NULL then 1 else 0 end) in_progress
from exams
where user_id = 1 and quiz_id = 114;"

result = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)

result.to_a.first
```

Reiteration of my questions:

1. Is it possible to write this query using Arel / ActiveRecord?  If so, how?
2. Is it "Rails convention" to use `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)` if you need to execute raw SQL in Rails?  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16963695/rails-way-to-write-a-complex-query) says it's best to run the SQL directly when it's complex and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14824453/rails-raw-sql-example) is where I found `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the easiest way to go through ActiveRecord would be something like this:

```
Exam.where(:user_id => 1, :quiz_id => 114).select(%q{
  sum(case when is_graded then 1 else 0 end) graded,
  sum(case when is_canceled then 1 else 0 end) canceled,
  sum(case when is_graded IS NULL and is_canceled IS NULL then 1 else 0 end) in_progress
})[0]
```

That will give you an `Exam` instance in `result` but this won't be a normal `Exam` with `id`, `is_graded`, ... attributes, this one will have `graded`, `canceled`, and `in_progress` attributes. You see, when you say `select('...')`, AR will produce objects whose attributes match the named columns in the SELECT clause.

Then a call to the `attributes` method should give you your Hash:

```
result = Exam.where(:user_id => 1, :quiz_id => 114).select(%q{...})[0].attributes
# result is now like {"graded"=>"2", "canceled"=>"2", "in_progress"=>"1"}
```

You could probably express those SUM and CASE expressions with AREL methods but it would be a big ugly mess so I wouldn't bother.

Comment: I used `[0]` instead of `first` because `Exam.where` returned an ActiveRecord relation object and was interpreting `first` as part of the query and adding `ORDER BY`.  Thank you for the excellent answer.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that the `first` versus `[0]` stuff. That might be version dependent, AR added a `LIMIT 1` when I checked but no `ORDER BY` and the results were the same. In any case, I switched it to `[0]` for safety's sake.